# How do I test a lawn mower magneto?

Tags: coil

I'm trying to test the magneto from my riding mower.  I followed some YouTube videos and tested it with a multimeter putting one probe where the spark plug would go and touching the other to the metal plates.  I get a resistance of about 5.84 kilo-ohms.  But I don't know what that means.  Is it too high?  Are there any other tests I should do?  (the mower has no spark).

The mower has a Briggs & Stratton 11.5hp engine, model 28D707-0123-01 (1996). I tested for a spark by holding the plug to the engine while turning the key.   (Maybe the "redneck" method but recommended by my service manual too in the absence of a spark tester.) The starter motor appears to work properly and the flywheel turns freely by hand.  I also tried a new spark plug and all the safety interlocks appear good. The replacement part is here https://www.jackssmallengines.com/jacks-parts-lookup/part/briggs-stratton/591459 but I can't find any specifications for the old or new one. I'm not yet 100% sure that the magneto is the problem so I'd rather confirm that it's bad before replacing it.

Comment: You want to test the ignition system? Or something else?

Comment: WE can't tell you if that's 'too high' or not because nobody here knows what lawn mower you're talking about or what it's specs are.   But 5.84k seems a pretty reasonable value for it.   It's (probably) just a coil of wire.   If it were close to zero ohms (shorted) or close to infinity (open), that'd be your clue the coil is bad.     HOw do you know you're not getting spark???   Redneck method is touch the spark-plugs tip to your mower, hold it there, and have somebody else pull the cord.   That's easier said than done.   And if you're not careful, you get a nice shock for your efforts

Comment: If you've a good heart and rubber boots, stick you finger in the spark-plug terminal and crank it over. If you feel a jolt it'll be working. Don't submerse yourself in water when doing this test. It kicks but it works. Government health warning alert!! Done it a few times in the past to check things and it never affected me arrrrrgggghhh.

Comment: @KyleB:  My father in law had my mother in law help him check out the spark a lawnmower.  He gave her a pair of insulated pliers and had her hold the sparkplug to the motor block while he cranked it.  Spark OK, check something else.  A few days later, a neighbor woman needed help with her lawnmower.  My father in law wasn't home, mother in law decided to help.  She got a pair of (uninsulated) pliers and went with the neighbor to have a look.  Neighbor woman holds the sparkplug in the uninsulated pliers, mother in law cranked the mower.  Here follows cursing and screaming.

Comment: @Andyaka   OK - I stand corrected.   THAT is the true 'redneck' method.     What I describe is the "foolish suburbanite redneck" method   ;)

Comment: @JRE    LOL     Well, I wish I could say I was surprised by that, but I'm not....    Fortunately nobody got hurt.    I blame Father-In-Law really - He should have indicated to Mother-In-Law the hazards and the reason he was giving her pliars with insulation.  He gave her a false sense of confidence.      I got zapped by my '78 Zephyr's ignition coil about 30 years ago.  My fingers tingled for days.

Comment: @user348514     Saw your edit.  I guess B&S have rednecks working there   ;)      I think realistically, you've done all you can in terms of "testing".  You may have to roll the dice and buy a new coil.    Before you do though, check that the coil is mounted close enough to the flywheel.  If there's too much gap, it can't create a spark.  I had that problem once - The mounting bolts for my coil got a tiny bit loose and the magneto moved fractions of an inch away.  Your manual might have a specification for the required gap.

Comment: @KyleB:  Definitely father in law's fault.  He needed a pair of hands to hold things and didn't explain at all.

Comment: When I was about 5 years old, a neighbor kid was on his front lawn. He called me over to try his Moon Machine. He said "Here, hold these 2 wires and you will see the moon when I turn the crank." Well, this little kid was too smart for that, but I stayed and watched other kids 'see the moon.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see the single spade terminal that is on the coil? If that is grounded, the coil won't fire. Pull the engine shroud off and disconnect the wire from that terminal. Next check the spacing from the coil to the flywheel is good. I like to use a business card but a thin piece of plastic works too. When the magnet is facing the coil the gap between the coil and magnet should be even and about that much.

Get a good new spark plug. Put it on the coil wire. Touch the threads of the spark plug to the block and have a second person crank it for you. This way you can easily keep an eye on the spark plug. If it does not spark at this point, you have a bad coil.

If it sparks then plug the wire back in. If the sparking stops then there is a short to ground on that wire.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I also found some tech. data that says the coil should have a resistance between 2-5k, so mine is a little high.  I try your suggestion to be sure but it probably looks like I need a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Seems those B&S (RIP) engines have some electronics in them (from US 4,270,509).

[image]

There's a spinning magnet attached to the flywheel which passes by the ignition coil module (called a "Magnetron" (tm) (sic)). As the coils enter the magnetic field, a voltage is induced in the coil 14 which turns the Darlington transistor on, which allows induced current to build up in the primary coil 110. As the magnet moves past the control coil, the Darlington turns off, the magnetic field in the core collapses and a high voltage is induced in the secondary 111 which causes a spark across the spark plug.

At higher RPM the voltages induced are higher so the transistor triggers earlier, as a kind of spark advance function.

So aside from the module itself, one should check out the kill switch 44 continuity to chassis (should be open for the motor to run), the magnet/coil alignment and the connections.

The coils can show continuity, but the transistor could be scuppered, for example.

There's not much to go wrong other than the module, but worth checking the kill switch.

This simple arrangement replaces the points (mechanical switch that operated once per spark plug firing) and "condenser" (capacitor) used in ignitions of old.